# How do I restore the good old style of syntax coloring for maven pom.xml in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

The style used be to with green tags, purple attribute names, bright blue for attribute values, and blue for comments.
Now in the latest version of Eclipse, the new style displays sky blue tags and XML chevrons in black.
I couldn't find a way to configure that in the Window->Preferences menu.
Best thing I could find is to use ant build.xml editor in the file associations so that it looks less worse than this terrible sky blue.

Comment: The Maven POM editor now embeds a different XML editor that looks and behaves differently. You can right-click and choose _Switch To Theme_ (in the preferences you will find those themes in _TextMate > Theme_) or you can go back to the old XML editor by installing the _M2E - POM Editor (Legacy) using WebTools SourceEditing UI_.

Comment: Installing "M2E Pom Editor (Legacy) using WebTools SourceEditing UI" worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: In my 2022-03 Eclipse version, I solved it in the following way.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74639229/is-it-possible-to-get-the-pom-editor-legacy-using-webtools-sourceediting-ui

Comment: Right-clicking in the POM XML editor window, and applying the TextMate theme as @howlger mentions, did the trick for me. Unfortunately, starting with Eclipse 2022-09, the M2E POM Editor (Legacy) approach no longer works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74639229/is-it-possible-to-get-the-pom-editor-legacy-using-webtools-sourceediting-ui

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by howgler, you can right-click and choose "Switch To Theme", but in Eclipse 2023-09 none of the available themes replicates the classic coloring scheme.  Fortunately you can find it on GitHub: among the [built-in themes](https://github.com/eclipse/tm4e/tree/main/org.eclipse.tm4e.ui/themes) of the TM4E project there is also "[WTP-XML-Classic.css](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/tm4e/main/org.eclipse.tm4e.ui/themes/WTP-XML-Classic.css)" labeled as "Theme replicating the coloring of the WTP XML editor".  A comment says that it was "Accidentally deleted". You can download it and add it in "Window > Preferences > TextMate > Theme".