# Is it possible to get the "POM Editor (Legacy) using WebTools SourceEditing UI" running in Eclipse 2022-09 or later?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

When doing a fresh install of Eclipse 2022-09, the legacy pom editor is not available to install anymore:

[image]

I can add an older update site:

[image]

And then select the legacy editor:

[image]

But the installation fails with this message:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: M2E - POM Editor (Legacy) using WebTools SourceEditing UI 1.18.3.20220122-2204 (org.eclipse.m2e.sse.ui.feature.feature.group 1.18.3.20220122-2204)
  Software currently installed: M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse 2.0.4.20220904-1703 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 2.0.4.20220904-1703)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    M2E Maven Integration for Eclipse Core 2.0.3.20220904-1703 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 2.0.3.20220904-1703)
    M2E Maven Integration for Eclipse Core 1.18.4.20220208-0831 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.18.4.20220208-0831)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: M2E Maven POM File XML Editor 1.18.3.20220122-2204 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml 1.18.3.20220122-2204)
    To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.16.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse 2.0.4.20220904-1703 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 2.0.4.20220904-1703)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.m2e.core [2.0.3.20220904-1703,2.0.3.20220904-1703]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: M2E - POM Editor (Legacy) using WebTools SourceEditing UI 1.18.3.20220122-2204 (org.eclipse.m2e.sse.ui.feature.feature.group 1.18.3.20220122-2204)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml [1.18.3.20220122-2204,1.18.3.20220122-2204]
```

Eclipse offers to resolve the conflict by uninstalling a few other features, but uninstalling the maven integration doesn't sound good:

[image]

More testing: Looks like the legacy POM editor also prevents updating a fresh install of 2022-06 (with legacy editor) to 2022-09 because of conflicting version dependencies for 'M2E Maven Integration for Eclipse Core':

[image]

More resources:

- https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg19384.html
- https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/138

Comment: Maybe this could be resolved by changing the allowed version ranges of the dependencies of the legacy pom editor (assuming there is no actual incompatibility, and the limitation to 1.x is arbitrary).

Comment: Thanks to the questioner, I was able to solve the problem. thank you (In the 2022-03 Eclipse version, it was possible to solve it by referring to the questioner's picture.) I was experiencing a problem in pom.xml where all letters were the same color.

Answer (score 2):

I reported an issue and the answer is no: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/1109